# How to edit the views in a forge model's bubblenode

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am working on a markup extension for autodesk forge. I want to be able to click on a position, save the camera information, and add it to the bubblenode as a view.

Does the forge api offer a way to edit the bubble node? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no and that's not just because Viewer doesn't offer APIs for that purpose.

Essentially when Viewer loads a buddle node as JSON object (typically parsed from a document as one of its model views) and as you can see it contains metadata for the model view e.g.:

```
data:
children: [{…}]
guid: "b3322d42-e636-4506-9605-7b869cf6d872"
hasThumbnail: "true"
name: "Scene"
progress: "complete"
role: "3d"
size: 20870311
status: "success"
success: "100%"
type: "geometry"
```

Viewer then uses this info to retrieve the URL to the corresponding derivatives from Forge services and dispatch them to an appropriate model loader. So to load markups as bubble nodes the catches are:

- There's no loader available with Viewer for its design data (neither SVG nor markup objects)
- Both the derivatives and their meta data are immutable on Forge services unless we regenerate them with translation jobs - yet you can still load them from your own setup, will discuss this later

At the moment the best appproach to save and load the markups is either as SVG literals (see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension) for details) or serialized markup objects.

Having said that it's possible (albeit not officially supported/documented) to come up with your own bubble node JSON for Viewer to consume - see [here](https://github.com/wallabyway/2DCompare/tree/master/docs/sheet1) for an example.

As for persisting the camera view you can save/load its state with `navigation.setView(camera.position, navigation.getTarget())` (see doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#getstate-filter)).

You can also persist the overall state of Viewer using `viewer.get/setState` (see doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#getstate-filter))